# Difference between applying slds classes to Div and to lightning element

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

This may be a basic question but I want to know that what is the difference between applying slds classes like `slds-grid--align-center slds-hide` to a `<div>` tag enclosing a lightning std component and applying them directly to lightning component, i.e :

```
<div aura:id="saveButtonID" class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-center slds-hide">
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="{!v.saveButtonLabel}" onclick="{! c.handleSave }" disabled="{!v.isSaveDisabled}" />
</div>
```

> VS

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="{!v.saveButtonLabel}" onclick="{! c.handleSave }" disabled="{!v.isSaveDisabled}" class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-center slds-hide"/>
```

And which one to preferably use. In some cases, the styling does not apply to later one abut if we enclose them in div tags, it works. Why is this so?

Comment: I can suggest to use developer tools - like in chrome, to inspect the 2 elements and see exactly the html that is generated